# How login in a website in python

Tags: python, http, http-post

Im trying to scrap [this site](http://www.empaquetador.cl/login) using this example code: https://github.com/kazuar/login_scraper_example/blob/master/login_scraper_example.py

But always print the login page and return 200 http code, what is wrong?

```
import requests
from lxml import html

USERNAME = "my_mail"
PASSWORD = "my_pwd"

LOGIN_URL = "http://www.empaquetador.cl"
URL = "http://www.empaquetador.cl/dashboard/turnos-historial?fecha=2017-12-01"  # this a available url after login success

def main():
    session_requests = requests.session()

    # Get login csrf token
    result = session_requests.get(LOGIN_URL)
    tree = html.fromstring(result.text)

    # Create payload
    payload = {
        "nombre": USERNAME,
        "contrasena": PASSWORD
    }

    # Perform login
    result = session_requests.post(LOGIN_URL, data = payload, headers = dict(referer = LOGIN_URL))

    # Scrape url
    result = session_requests.get(URL, headers = dict(referer = URL))
    tree = html.fromstring(result.content)
    bucket_names = tree.xpath("//div[@class='tbl-generales table-nohover table table-bordered']/a/text()")

    print(bucket_names)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: did you print `tree` as well?

Comment: i edit the post, forget to change that print when copying the code, sorry

Comment: did you check `csrf token` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The login form has `action` set to `/login/index/process`

```
<form id="login" name="login" class="form-horizontal" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="/login/index/process" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

You need to set LOGIN_URL to the same in order to post the form to the correct URL:

```
LOGIN_URL = "http://www.empaquetador.cl/login/index/process"
```